# FOR loop with conditional strings

Tags: python

In my code I have for loop to a dict... and I get desired output as shown below..

```
dict = {"apple":5,"banana":3, "mangos":2}
columns = ('apple', 'banana','mangos')
for column in columns:
    value = dict.get(column)
    print column,value
```

Output:

```
apple 5
banana 3
mangos 2
```

But if my dict changes to

```
dict = {"apple":5,"Oranges":3, "mangos":2}
```

the same for loop would give me following output

```
columns = ('apple', 'banana','mangos')
for column in columns:
    value = dict.get(column)
    print column,value
```

I get following, which is expected

```
apple 5
banana None
mangos 2
```

Now the question is, is there a way I can set the column loop

```
columns = ('apple', 'banana','mangos')
```

so that the second value 'banana' could be either 'banana' or 'orange' ?

Comment: what would you want the output to be in the second example?

Comment: why do you have to predefine the columns and not just iterate over the dict keys? Then it will be `banana` if the dict contains `bananas` or `orange` if it contains `orange` as keys.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Perhaps because order matters, in which case an `OrderedDict` would be the way to go

Comment: In the second example i would want the output to be Oranges 3....

Comment: An *ad hoc* solution to this particular question is trivial, like `dict.get(column, dict.get('orange'))`, but I strongly suspect this is an XY problem. What are you trying to do?

Comment: @brianpck Another solution would be this: `columns = ('apple', 'banana','mangos') if 'banana' in dict else ('apple', 'orange','mangos')`. Note that the `.get()` method can take a second argument which in your case can be 0 ("what do i do if there is no suck key in the dict?").

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Oh I just thought of that solution too, I like your solution more if it has only 2 options. If it has more than I feel defining if statements are better, more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
d = {"apple":5,"banana":3, "orange":2}
c = ('apple', 'banana','mangos')

# print direct values
for k, v in d.items():
    print k, v

# print any values of the predefined columns + additionnal ones
ext = set(list(c) + d.keys())
for col in ext:
    print col, d.get(col)
```

Ouput 1 :

> orange 2
>
> apple 5
>
> banana 3

Ouput 2:

> orange 2
>
> mangos None
>
> apple 5
>
> banana 3

Answer (score 3):

```
dict = {"apple":5,"oranges":3, "mangos":2}
columns = ('apple', 'banana' , 'oranges','mangos')
for column in columns:
    value = dict.get(column)
    if value:
        print(column,value)
```

Check if the value is there or not and then print it or OrderedDict, There's too many good answers, you could check if in the dict has 'oranges' or 'banana' and then change your `columns` based on what you find.

```
dict = {"apple":5,"oranges":3, "mangos":2}
if 'banana' in dict:  
    columns = ('apple', 'banana','mangos') 
else:
    columns = ('apple', 'oranges','mangos') 
for column in columns:
    value = dict.get(column)
    print(column,value)
```

Edited to use `if 'banana' in dict` because of Ev. Kounis's comment! Thanks.

Comment: I think it would be better for the check to be `if 'banana' not in dict` since it might be in there with a value that has a bool of False like 0 for example. Also the name `dict` is to be avoided since it shadows the built-in

Comment: Oh true! I forgot about that, still stupidly early where I live, thank you will update